# Entries added to dictionary get overwritten

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

There is a dictionary initialized, serializer provides some data and adding to a nested array is made by iterating list of items:

```py
list = {"shopping_list": []}
item = {}
count = 0

stuff = json.loads(serializer.data["stuff_file"])

for s in stuff:
  item["level"] = count
  item["position"] = count * 10
  item["item_name"] = s["name"]

  list["shopping_list"].append(item)
  count += 1
```

But instead of receiving a list of unique items (expected the `append` method to do that), I get the list with proper count of items, but all previous ones are overwritten by the most recent one, like:

```
{
    "shopping_list": [
        {
            "level": 2,
            "position": 20,
            "item_name": "Bronze Badge"

        },
        {
            "level": 2,
            "position": 20,
            "item_name": "Bronze Badge"

        },
        {
            "level": 2,
            "position": 20,
            "item_name": "Bronze Badge"

        }
    ]
}
```

How should I write to the list to have all of the items unique, e.g.:

```
{
    "shopping_list": [
        {
            "level": 0,
            "position": 0,
            "item_name": "Gold Badge"

        },
        {
            "level": 1,
            "position": 10,
            "item_name": "Silver Badge"

        },
        {
            "level": 2,
            "position": 20,
            "item_name": "Bronze Badge"

        }
    ]
}
```

?

Comment: Create the item variable inside the loop itself.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Actually it's not even needed. OP can simply do `list["shopping_list"].append({'level': count, 'position': count * 10, 'item_name': s['name']})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the variable outside the loop, create `item` inside it:

```
list = {"shopping_list": []}
count = 0

stuff = [{"name": "Gold Badge"}, {"name": "Silver Badge"}, {"name": "Bronze Badge"}]

for s in stuff:
  item = {}
  item["level"] = count
  item["position"] = count * 10
  item["item_name"] = s["name"]

  list["shopping_list"].append(item)
  count += 1

print(list)
```

Output:

```
{'shopping_list': [{'level': 0, 'position': 0, 'item_name': 'Gold Badge'}, {'level': 1, 'position': 10, 'item_name': 'Silver Badge'},{'level': 2, 'position': 20, 'item_name': 'Bronze Badge'}]}
```

As @DeepSpace pointed out, you can also use a dictionary literal:

```
for s in stuff:
  list["shopping_list"].append({'level': count, 'position': count * 10, 'item_name': s['name']})
  count += 1
```

In fact, you could get rid of the count variable and do this as well:

```
for count, s in enumerate(stuff):
  list["shopping_list"].append({'level': count, 'position': count * 10, 'item_name': s['name']})
```

Comment: No need to create `item`. Instead use a dict literal. `list["shopping_list"].append({'level': count, 'position': count * 10, 'item_name': s['name']})` Clear of bugs and 4 lines shorter

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks! Added it to my answer.